# In_array not working - compare two files

Tags: php

The code below is a simple version of what I am trying to do. The code will read in two files, see if there is a matching entry and, if there is, display the difference in the numbers for that item. But it isn't working. The first echo displays the word but the second echo is never reached. Would someone please explain what I am missing?

```
    $mainArry = array('Albert,8');
    $arry =     array('Albert,12');

    foreach ($arry as $line) {
        $kword = explode(',', $line); 
        echo 'kword '.$kword[0];
        if (in_array($kword[0], $mainArry)) {
            echo 'line '.$line. ' has count of '.$kword[1] . '<br>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your first array only contains 1 element, `Albert,8` . Is that intended or did you instead want to have 2 items stored as `["Albert", 8]` ?

Comment: It looks like you are searching $mainArray for the kword of 'Albert', but $mainArray only has 'Albert,8', so it won't match.

Comment: One of the benefits of answers on stackoverflow is that they may help other users with similar questions. Since your question is really quite contrived, it achieves very little in this regard. It would have been better for you to give more perspective on what it is you are trying to achieve and why you chose to do it a particular way. This not only helps improve the quality of answers but improves the likelihood your question will better serve the community. Always write your questions with other questioners in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $mainArry contains a single element: the string `'Albert,8'`. It looks like you want to use it as an array (elements `'Albert'` and `'8'`) instead of a string.

You mention the code will read from two files, so you can 'explode' it to a real array, as you do with $arry. A simpler approach would be using [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to parse the CSV string into $mainArry.

```
$inputString = 'Albert,8';
$mainArry = str_getcsv($inputString); // now $mainArry is ['Albert','8']
$arry =     array('Albert,12');

foreach ($arry as $line) {
    $kword = explode(',', $line); 
    echo 'kword '.$kword[0];
    if (in_array($kword[0], $mainArry)) {
        echo 'line '.$line. ' has count of '.$kword[1] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Test it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/629bc3cb045320f72f02eb18fd15ee050ca1e5fb).

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to compare the string `Albert` with `Albert,8`, so they won't match. If you want to check if the string contains the keyword, assuming your array has more than one element, you could use:

```
$mainArry = array('Albert,8');
$arry =     array('Albert,12');

foreach ($arry as $line) {
    $kword = explode(',', $line); 
    echo 'kword '.$kword[0];
    foreach ($mainArry as $comp) {
        if (strstr($comp, $kword[0])) {
            echo 'line '.$line. ' has count of '.$kword[1] . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

example: https://eval.in/728566

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend your way of working, but this is a solution, basically the process you apply to the `$arry` should also apply to the `$mainArry` you're trying to compare it to.

```
 $mainArry = array('Albert,8');
    $arry =     array('Albert,12');

/***
NEW function below takes the valus out of the main array.
    and sets them in their own array so they can be properly compared. 
***/
 foreach ($mainArry as $arrr){
 $ma = explode(",",$arrr);
 $names[] = $ma[0];
 $values[] = $ma[1];
 }
 unset($arrr,$ma);


    foreach ($arry as $line) {
        $kword = explode(',', $line); 
        echo 'kword '.$kword[0];
        /// note var reference here is updated. 
        if (in_array($kword[0], $names)) {
            echo '<br>line '.$kword[0]. ' has count of '.$kword[1] . '<br>';
        }
    }
```

> Yeah, [MarcM's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41986594/3536236) does the same thing in a neat single line, but I wanted to illustrate a little more under the hood operations of the value setting. `:-/`